# How to enable quarkus.flyway.clean-at-start only for DEV namespace in K8S

Tags: java, flyway, quarkus

I have created a microservice with https://quarkus.io/ and I am using the extension [Flyway](https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway) for the migration.

The microservice is going to be deployed on DEV and PROD namespace into K8S cluster.
On the DEV namespace, I would like to the set property [clean-at-start](https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway#quarkus-flyway_quarkus.flyway.clean-at-start) to true and on the PROD namespace to false.

My question, how to assign different value to `quarkus.flyway.clean-at-start` depends on K8S `NAMESPACE`.
I assume, I have to do it, when the container gets started.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so:

- Create multiple property files for different application profiles
- Add prefix to properties for Profiles

[Background information](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference): tl;dr; Keep in mind that the properties are always read in a fixed order. The generic property file at first and then the ones for currently active profiles and if there are properties set redundently they are overwriting each other. If they are not mentioned the one of the global file (or default) is taken.

Multi-File Approach: Simply add new files names like: `application-dev.properties`. All properties for the related profile can be named there. Usually you solve your request like:

- application.properties  -> Global one and default for all
- application-DEV.properties  -> source of truth for DEV (overwrites)
- application-PROD.properties -> ..

Prefix:
I think thats the common approach on quarkus. Simply add %DEV.quarkus.... as prefix top a property that should be leading for a special profile. For you this would make it look like:

```
# Gloablly taken and save fallback
quarkus.flyway.clean-at-start=false
# Taken / Overwriting when DEV profile is used (%PROD. for other profile)
%DEV.quarkus.flyway.clean-at-start=true
```